# Is it possible to do all user interface stuff using code in Android and iOS

Tags: android, swift, user-interface, layout, xcode-storyboard

I've seen some Android and iOS projects in some companies which their layouts or views are created using code.

For example, in Android, there are no layouts such as [Telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) source code and in iOS, there is not any storyboard.

Is it possible to do all UI stuff using the code?
Is it the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, but why in the world would you want to waste the time getting the layout just right when visual layout tools make it trivial.

No, it’s definitely not best practice to ignore the layout tools and do it yourself in code.

Comment: so why some Applications are designed just with code?

Comment: Usually, when I’ve seen it it’s either because that’s what they learned or out of some mistaken “optimization” argument.  http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1513451

Answer (score 0):

first of all ,yes its possible to do all ui stuff using code.and yes again for best practice methods for layouts because when ur making a large app then its not possible to do all ui stuff on xml layouts.for example when ur working with rest apis and u have to add some ui stuff like button or fragments or layouts then its the best way to use code rather than layouts.

Comment: In my project I have layouts and in some parts I generate UI, for example, buttons and text inputs. but not all UI. if layouts ad storyboards are not good to design large apps, Why there are such tools in IDEs?